# C# generics and subclassing - why must I not give the type parameter on ctor? (simple)

Tags: c#

I have

```
public class LDBList<T> : List<T> where T : LDBRootClass {
    public LDBList<T>(LDBList<T> x) : base(x) { }  // not allowed
    public LDBList   (LDBList<T> x) : base(x) { }  // allowed
    ...
}
```

Why is the generic type not accepted on the constructor?

Comment: The constructor does not contain any type parameter list, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#instance-constructors (but methods can, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#methods).

Comment: I was hoping for a reason but because microsoft says so is OK.

Comment: @user3779002 If you want a reason - well, the reason is that it's entirely unnecessary. Having a `<T>` parameter on the constructor name doesn't mean anything nor does it help the compiler at all. I suppose it would be a thing *if* any class (generic or non-generic) could have additional generic-type parameters for its constructor, but C# and the CLI does not allow that (i.e. constructors *cannot* have additional generic type parameters), so that's why it isn't a thing.

Comment: @Dai "I suppose it would be a thing if any [generic] class could have additional generic-type parameters for its constructor, but C# [...] does not allow that" Yep, not coincidentally that's what's being said on my subsequent question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64194477/c-sharp-subclassing-with-generics-i-need-an-extra-generic-parameter-for-ctor-b#64194575>

Answer (score 2):

The language does not support generic constructors. Have a look at the [grammar for constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#instance-constructors):

```
constructor_declaration
    : attributes? constructor_modifier* constructor_declarator constructor_body
    ;
```

Compare that with the [grammar for methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#methods):

```
method_declaration
    : method_header method_body
    ;

method_header
    : attributes? method_modifier* 'partial'? return_type member_name type_parameter_list?
      '(' formal_parameter_list? ')' type_parameter_constraints_clause*
    ;
```

The grammar for methods includes a `type_parameter_list`, and a `type_parameter_constraints_clause`, which the grammar for constructors does not.

Even if it did, it is unclear what your code means, because you are declaring a type parameter with the same name as an existing type parameter - the `T` declared in the class.

Comment: I think the OP is asking why the class constructor's *name* doesn't have a generic type parameter (not a generic type argument).